# Product status not changing when qty goes below minimum qty

Tags: magento-1.6, inventory, quantity

I am using magento-1.6.1.0

When qty of poduct goes below minimum qty still it show product "In stock".

I have set everything prodperly on system > config > tab.

still facing the same issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause of the issue, while uploading product through Magmi, It's status was set to "In stock". since direct hits query to db. No validations applied.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you have the 'Allow backorders' set to 'Yes'.
Or the stock index does not run.